# Facebook PHP API: What is the $session var in the documentation examples?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

The following is the PHP example on Facebook's documentation guide for posting a message to the feed of an FB Page:

```
/* make the API call */
$request = new FacebookRequest(
  $session,
  'POST',
  '/{page-id}/feed',
  array (
    'message' => 'This is a test message',
  )
);
$response = $request->execute();
$graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
/* handle the result */
```

Note the `$session` var as one of the params in the `FacebookRequest`. Could someone please tell me what this var is exactly? What exactly is assigned to it, and how do I create/receive this data?

Comment: It is using the SDK you find here: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4

Answer (score 0):

You can get a session using one of the helpers like the [redirect helper](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper/4.0.0) or [JavaScript helper](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/FacebookJavaScriptLoginHelper/4.0.0).

If you already have an access token you can create a session with `FacebookSession`.

```
use Facebook\FacebookSession;
$session = new FacebookSession('access-token');
```

The `FacebookSession` has nothing to do with `$_SESSION`'s. It's better to think of it as representing **a user who is logged in with a particular access token**.